# AttributeError when reading ASCII ply file with plyfile's Plydata.read

Tags: python, python-3.7, ply-file-format

I am trying to write a short script to convert a text file containing point coordinates to a binary ply file. The idea was to add a header to the beginning, change the file type to ASCII ply, then read it with plyfile and write to a binary ply. I would do this manually with CloudCompare or Meshlab, but I have a few thousand files to convert.

I got to where I had an ASCII ply file that I could open with CloudCompare, but I get an AttributeError when I try to use PlyData.read. I get the same error when I try to run it on a file saved directly from CloudCompare.

Here is what I reduced the code to for debugging:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Request input if no system arguments found
    try:
        inputDirName = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        inputDirName = input('Enter directory containing ASCII ply files:\n')
    os.chdir(inputDirName)

    files = glob('*.ply')
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r+') as f:
            data = PlyData.read(f)
            PlyData([data]).write(file.split('.')[0] + '_binary.ply')
```

Here is the error I get when I run it

```
File "C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\plyfile.py", line 392, in read
   data = PlyData._parse_header(stream)
File "C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\plyfile.py", line 373, in _parse_header                         
   while parser.consume(stream.readline()):
File "C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\plyfile.py", line 120, in consume
   line = raw_line.decode('ascii').strip()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your task is only to convert multiple files from ply ascii to ply binary, you can use meshlabserver, the command line version of meshlab that is scriptable and well suited to this kind of task.

Moreover if you feel really brave you could even try the upcoming pymeshlab ( https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/PyMeshLab ) e.g. python binding for all the meshlab functionality; currently (2020 August) it is in a very alpha state, but already almost usable...

Comment: I was unable to get either option to work correctly, but I suspect the security settings on my work computer are somewhat to blame.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question about the AttributeError, but I was able to work around the problem by parsing the file into a numpy array myself. The end result looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from glob import glob
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Request input if no system arguments found
    try:
        inputDirName = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        inputDirName = input('Enter directory containing files to be converted:\n')
    os.chdir(inputDirName)
    
    files = glob('*.txt')
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r+') as f:
            # Get number of vertices
            vertices = int(f.readline())
            
            # Create empty numpy array and define datatypes
            numpyArray = np.empty(vertices,dtype=[('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'), ('z', 'f4'),
                                 ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])
            
            # Read file contents into array
            for index, line in enumerate(f):
                x, y, z, r, g, b = line.strip().split(' ')
                numpyArray[index] = (x, y, z, r, g, b)
            
            # Create PlyElement instance
            el = PlyElement.describe(numpyArray, 'vertex',
                                     comments=['Created ' + str(datetime.now())])
            
            # Write to binary ply file
            binaryFile = file.split('.')[0] + '_binary.ply'
            PlyData([el]).write(binaryFile)
            
        print('Saved ' + binaryFile)
```